# logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions opens "You have already authorized MyApp" screen

Tags: parse-platform, pffacebookutils

I updated to ParseFacebookUtilsV4 (1.9.0) with FBSDKLoginKit (4.7.0)..(with IOS 9)
so after calling "logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions"

```
[PFFacebookUtils logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile", @"email",@"user_friends"] block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error)
```

first of all it opens Safari - I guess it's their new UX - is that true? or its another problem?(used to open app, using IOS 9)

T problem that everytime - in my first login and after a logout as well -  I connect it shows me "You have already authorized MyApp..." screen in The safari browser.

I Tried to call

```
[[PFFacebookUtils facebookLoginManager] logOut];
```

but it didn't help.

Thanks, Dan

Comment: Same.  Did you find a solution?

Comment: Nothing new:/ just small thing - if you the user logged in with "system account" this wiil help:
[[PFFacebookUtils facebookLoginManager] setLoginBehavior:FBSDKLoginBehaviorSystemAccount];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you log out, you have already granted the app permissions so once you log back in that's why you'll get the "already authorized" message. If you want to have to grant permissions again, you'll need to go to your [App Settings on Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications) and remove the application. Then when you try to authorize the app again, you will see the permission granting dialog.

Comment: No idea what the downvote is about. Wish they'd commented.